# Why this select query to Oracle(View) doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

First I tested simple cases:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":paramCode", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = userCode;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VIEWUSERDATA WHERE  Codigo = :paramCode";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Works, retrieve data
}
```

Another:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":paramRole", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = userRole;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VIEWUSERDATA WHERE  Role = :paramRole";
...
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Also works
}
```

But when join, doesn't work.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":paramCode", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = userCode;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":paramRole", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = userRole;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VIEWUSERDATA WHERE Role = :paramRole AND Code = :paramCode";
...
while (reader.Read())//don't retrieve anything
{
}
```

Data exists, If I do the query in an external query editor(window) works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any rows returning when you execute just the last query? the first 2 queries might work, but the for the last query, the 'where' condition is different.

Comment: What types are userCode and userRole? Just strings?

Comment: Try using OR rather than AND, it should work.  The problem is that there is no row with that Role and that Code.

Comment: @paqogomez The types are string(OracleDbType.NVarchar2)

Comment: @HappyLee When I do the query in a External Tool, like SQL Manager For Oracle, etc works.

Comment: @Casperah Exist one row with that Role and that Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Oracle parameter binding is by position, not by name. Either swap the two `cmd.Parameters.Add` calls or set `cmd.BindByName = true;` before executing the query.